# How to use jquery libraries with opal-jquery?

Tags: ruby, opalrb

So I'm using `opal`, `opal-jquery`, and `jquery.terminal`. The latter adds a function to jquery called `terminal()`.

However `Element` doesn't seem to have that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call

```
Element.expose(:terminal)
```

Before trying to use the method and that should work.

Comment: Wow, that absolutely worked, where is this documented?

Comment: Docs for opal are lacking, I'm used to read the source code of its library:
https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery/blob/master/lib/opal/jquery/element.rb#L115-L132